# Understanding about Pagination

Tags: json, laravel, api, pagination, bitbucket

Hi Can someone explain to me what this means?

```
{#274 ▼
  +"pagelen": 10
  +"next": "https://bitbucket.org/!api/2.0/repositories/spycetek?page=2"
  +"values": array:10 [▶]
  +"page": 1
  +"size": 59
}
```

what does pagelen means?
and the size? 
I just need to fully understand this. thanks

Comment: What language are you attempting to use?

Comment: Your API is assembling some form of paginator for the data. You will have to look at your code to see how this is created. Its not a standard Laravel response. If I had to guess, pagelen is the number of items per page, but size could be total records or the total pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{#274 ▼
  +"pagelen": 10  // no of data on one page
  +"next": "https://bitbucket.org/!api/2.0/repositories/spycetek?page=2"  // next page link
  +"values": array:10 [▶]  contents of the page
  +"page": 1  // current page number
  +"size": 59  // i think total number of pages
}
```

you can always refer to laravel documentations.